# Show error for django unique_together in CreateView form

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django CBV CreateView and have a unique_together setting on the model

```
class Meta:
    unique_together = ('field1', 'field2',)
```

When the user adds a non-unique new record, it triggers an error at the database level, which is a 500 error. I'd like to instead just explain to the user that their entry was a duplicate and to add something else.

Any idea for an easy way to do this with CBV and the unique_together setting (or a validator)? I'd like to keep this at the model level so the unique check happens regardless if the user creates, edits, or if an admin does it in the Django admin.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you add these new instances? If you add them by a form (the admin site would automatically make a form and use it or use the form class you set it to use) such errors should not happen as it calls the models `full_clean()` method which in turn calls `validate_unique` which should validate all uniqueness constraints.

Comment: By any chance do you override the forms `clean` method and don't call super?

Answer (score 0):

You can overide clean methond in ModelForm to validate unique_togther

```
class AwesomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        if Model.objects.filter(field1=cleaned_data['field1'],         
                                   field2=cleaned_data['field1').exists():
            raise ValidationError(
                  'Solution with this Name already exists for this problem')

        return cleaned_data
```

Comment: So you're saying this is impossible: "I'd like to keep this at the model level so the unique check happens regardless if the user creates, edits, or if an admin does it in the Django admin."

Comment: You can still keep the ```unique_together``` in the model's Meta class, If you override the clean method in forms.py that won't affect the Django admin.